# Viewer errors with version 7.93 (release 10/05/23)

Tags: autodesk-viewer

The APS Viewer was updated on 5/10 to version 7.93.
Since then, we've noticed that the functions used to manages objects have been altered (errors on Frags).

When preparing Frags to apply a SetThemingColor or the VibilityManager, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: Cannot read private member #F from an object whose class did not declare it
```

Error in RenderModel.js file

For each of the problem areas, we use InstanceTree and enumNodeFragments.
On previous versions, everything went smoothly.

Thanks to you if you have any idea of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [JavaScript Proxy Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to proxy viewer Model objects, then you must update your proxy definition like below, as [JavaScript Proxy Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) doesn't forward private properties.

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let modelProxy = new Proxy(model , {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        const value = target[prop];
        if (value instanceof Function) {
          //console.log(target, prop, receiver)
          return function (...args) {
            //console.log(arguments, args);
            return value.apply(this === receiver ? target : this, ...args);
          };
        }
        return value;
      }
});


modelProxy.setThemingColor([12567, new THREE.Vector4(1,0,0,1)]);
viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#no_private_property_forwarding

Comment: Thanks, @Eason,  indeed, I use Vuejs proxy to instantiate the models. I will follow your suggestion.